# Javascript photo slideshow not showing images

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, slideshow

I am using a simple JavaScript slideshow but am having problems displaying the pictures. After like picture #13 I start getting the red X image place holder. Not sure why, because if I right click on the image and go to properties and check the image source it does exist. I have a total of about 126 pictures at about 1.7 MB average size for each photo. I notice that IE Memory usage can go up to 1 GB.

I have this slideshow on a SharePoint 2007 page.

```
<!-- Original Source http://www.scribd.com/doc/13618938/Add-a-Slide-Show-on-a-Share-Point-Site-Using-Javascript-HTML-and-Content-Editor-Web-Part -->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var folderDir = "/images/my-images_2012/"
var slideShowSpeed = 3000
var crossFadeDuration = 3

// Specify the image files 
var Pic = new Array()
var i=1

for (var k=1;k<=126;k++)
{
     Pic[i] = folderDir +  "ENC_2012_0" + k + ".JPG"
     i++
}

var t
var j = 1
var p = Pic.length

var preLoad = new Array() 
for (i = 1; i < p; i++){
                preLoad[i] = new Image()
                preLoad[i].src = Pic[i]
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// The function to do the "slide show"
//------------------------------------------------------------------

function runSlideShow()
{

    if (document.all){ 
                document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=2)" 
                document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDu ration)"
                document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Apply()
    }

    document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[j].src

    if (document.all){ 
        document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Play() 
    }

    j=j+1 

    if (j > (p-1)) j=1
    t = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed) 
}

// Add the following line to get the JS to run 
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runSlideShow"); 

</script>


<DIV align=left>
<TABLE style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #288118; BORDER-SPACING: 0px; WIDTH: 358px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; HEIGHT: 341px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #288118" height=300 width=300>
<P align=left><IMG name=SlideShow align=left src="/images/my-images_2012/ENC_2012_01.JPG" width=334 height=300></P> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TR>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
```

Comment: use photo in size 1.7M is not a good practice, slide them up is even worse. Try change the format of the picture (e.g. jpeg) and set to smaller size e.g. (width=334 height=300).

Answer (score 0):

You're loading 126 images at the same time. At about `1.7 MB` each, that's about **`214.2 MB`** you're trying to load at once.

Bad idea.

Try using thumbnails instead, or at least load the images sequentially:

```
var current = 0;
function imgLoaded() {
    if(current > 0){ // Remove the previous event listener.
        preLoad[current - 1].onload = null;
    }
    preLoad[current] = new Image();
    preLoad[current].src = Pic[current];
    current++;
    if(current < p){
        preLoad[current-1].onload = imgLoaded;
    }
}
imgLoaded();
```

(Not tested, but this should work)

Comment: Bit of a Javascript noob here. Not sure how to include that in my code.

Comment: Replace: `for (i = 1; i < p; i++){
                preLoad[i] = new Image()
                preLoad[i].src = Pic[i]
}` with my code, that should do the trick. (That's the `for` loop before your `'The function to do the "slide show"'` comment.)

Comment: Geting the error: `Unable to set value of the property 'onload': object is null or undefined ` on the line `preLoad[current].onload = imgLoaded();`.

Comment: Whoops, remove the `()` in that line (Updated answer);

Comment: Did you remove `var preLoad = new Array()`? (In case you did, add it back)

Comment: At first I thought I did, but it is there.

Comment: `'preLoad[...]' is null or not an object` on the line `preLoad[current].onload = imgLoaded;`

Comment: Made a small tweak: `preLoad[current-1].onload = imgLoaded;`

Comment: Same error, but on line `document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[j].src`

Comment: And that's because you're trying to `runSlideShow()` a image that isn't loaded yet. Try replacing `if (j > (p-1)) j=1` with `if (j > (preLoad.length-1)) j=1`

Comment: `'preLoad[...].src' is null or not an object` on `document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[j].src
`